# NTLM authentication with BackgroundDownloader in metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, download, winrt-xaml

I want to use BackgroundDownloader class to download files from some external repository which uses NTLM authentication, So i need to pass NTLM authentication header in request from my WindowsStoreApp.
I tried using ServerCredential property, however it looks like I cannot use this in case of NTLM
I can use HttpWebRequest/WebRequest  class and use NetworkCredentials but then I have to take care of downloading features like Resume, Stop, Pause which is supported by BackgroundDownloader.
The another way is to add a header with "Authorization" in request but then i need to take care of generating the NTLM auth token.
Is there any way i can use BackgroundDownloader with NTLM authentication ?
Suggestion please ... 
Thanks